# Java Class not found exception if running from jar, running fine if run from IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, jar, manifest.mf

This is my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.ttn.dailyreport.RunTest</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

And this is the manifest.mf -

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Shubham
Class-Path: poi-3.17.jar commons-codec-1.10.jar commons-collections4-4
 .1.jar opencsv-4.0.jar commons-lang3-3.6.jar commons-text-1.1.jar com
 mons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar commons-logging-1.2.jar commons-collections-
 3.2.2.jar postgresql-42.2.2.jar log4j-1.2.17.jar mail-1.4.7.jar activ
 ation-1.1.1.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.2
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_161
Main-Class: com.ttn.dailyreport.RunTest

It has all the external jars in classpath still throwing class not found exception. Let me know if you need more details or code.

Comment: And you have all those jars in the manifest next to your jar file?

Comment: No. How can we package these jars? Can you pls share the right pom structure I need to follow?

Comment: You have a lot to learn!  The exact way to package a Java application depends on where it needs to go.

Comment: That I know. Btw thanks for letting me know.